# Funcion exportar a Excel con parametros PHP

Tags: php, csv

Quiero adaptar esta función que uso para exportar la DB completo a Excel a una función que pasandole un parametro (paq) me devuelta un excel con las coincidencias de la DB.

Mi HTML del botón.

```
<button onclick="Export()" class="btn btn-primary">Exportar a Excel</button>
```

Función Export en JS.

```
function Export()
        {

            var conf = confirm("Exportar a CSV?");
            if(conf == true)
            {
                window.open("pasajeros/export.php", '_blank');
            }
        }
```

Y el export.php

```
<?php

require("ajax/db_connection2.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    exit(mysqli_error($con));
}

$users = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $users[] = $row;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=EMT_Pasajeros.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Nombre', 'Apellido', 'Email', 'F.Nacimiento', 'Telefono', 'Tel.Seguro', 'Paquete','$ VENTA', '$ EMISIÓN', '$ NETA', 'DNI', 'Vendedor', 'Link Comprobante'));

if (count($users) > 0) {
    foreach ($users as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
}
?>
```

Quisiera saber cómo vincular el parámetro del Export('parametro') del onlick, con la función de JS y que ese parametro se lo pase al pasajeros/export.php para que haga la consulta a la DB con el WHERE parametro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones. Puedes usar el método de respuesta `GET` (minimo de cambios en tu código, pero menos seguro) o el método de respuesta `POST` (más cambios al código, pero más seguro) para lograr tu objetivo. Primero, para recibir este párametro en la función de JS (de donde sea que lo obtengas) y enviarlo con estos métodos, harias algo como esto:

**GET**

```
function Export(parametro)
{
    var conf = confirm("Exportar a CSV?");
    if(conf == true)
    {
        window.open("pasajeros/export.php?parametro="+parametro, '_blank');
    }
}
```

**POST**

```
function Export(parametro)
{
    var conf = confirm("Exportar a CSV?");
    if(conf == true)
    {
        var mdr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        mdr.open("POST", "pasajeros/export.php", true);
        mdr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        mdr.send("parametro="+parametro);
    }
}
```

Para obtener este parámetro del lado de PHP

**GET**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$GET["parametro"];
```

**POST**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$POST["parametro"];
```

Como puedes observar, en la parte de `JavaScript` incluimos el parametro en la `url` que se requiere, y en la parte de `PHP` accedemos al parametro gracias a la variable super global `GET`/`POST`, que es un arreglo.

**Post Respuesta**

- Siempre debes desconfiar de lo que cualquiera de tus usuarios
  introduzca. No sé de donde obtendrás ese parametro del cual estamos
  hablando, pero ahora más que nunca es importante parametrizar todas
  tus consultas dinámicas y evitar asi la Inyección SQL. Por lo cual te recomiendo mucho leer esta otra pregunta que habla de eso: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! Pero aún no lo puedo hacer funcionar.Con GET me dice:   "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"(lo cual no encuentro lo que está sintácticamente mal), y con POST el botón no hace nada, solo tira en consola "XHR finished loading"

Comment: @Santiago ese error es porque tu consulta esta mal hecha. Espero que no hayas copiado literalmente lo que yo puse en la consulta, porque obviamente yo no se como es tu tabla. Solo era un ejemplo de como usar el parametro.

Comment: El Export lo copié tal cual y la $query la cambié para adaptar el parametro que busco, así: 
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE paq = ".$POST["parametro"];
No sé si había que cambiar algo más.

Comment: @Santiago Pues depende. No se que tipo de dato guarde "paq", pero si es una cadena, tienes que encerrar entre comillas el parametro, algo asi $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE paq =´ ".$POST["parametro"]." ´ ";

Comment: Es string, y sí con ese formato ya funciona. Si entro directamente al export.php me exporta un csv vacio, lo cual es correcto ya que no tiene ningun parametro, quería probar que funciona el export.php. Lo que no logro es que execute la consulta con el parametro que le paso. En el onclick del botón HTML le puse un estring con este formato Export('prueba') y me tendría que devolver los que cumplan con paq=prueba, pero me devuelve un csv vacio. Ya comprobé que hay un paq=prueba en la DB.

Comment: @Santiago Pues... la verdad no estoy muy seguro de que podría estar pasando. Podria ser que el parametro no esta llegando bien (hay que probar poner comillas en algunos partes) o podria ser en la base de datos. Debes entender que de mi lado es muy dificil saber exactamente que esta pasando. Quizas puedes aislar el problema para saber que es lo que no esta funcionando bien y comentarme por aca o hacer otra pregunta. Tambien si mi pregunta te ayudo en tu problema especifico (que creo que si) puedes marcarla como aceptada, eso ayuda a mantener el sitio limpio

Comment: Lo voy a tratar de solucionar! Muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda. Me sirvió mucho.

Comment: De nada. Le di un voto positivo a tu pregunta. Llegaste a 20 de reputacion. Con eso ya puedes participar en el chat. Si tienes preguntas cortas puedes ir al chat y alli te ayudaran mas rapido. Saludos y suerte!